# Dynamically adding rows to a table using attribute directive in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to display a table on my HTML page. The table will contain multiple rows. On clicking the '+' icon of a row(let's call it R1), I call an attribute directive to fetch data and display it in a new row(R2) which should be added below the clicked row(R1).

But currently, the data isn't getting displayed and I get a blank row(R2) added below the clicked row(R1).

The code for directive is:

```
angular.module(
  "app", []
).controller(
  'Ctrl', [
    "$scope",
    function(
      $scope
    ) {
      $scope.items = {
        "first": {
          "name": "item1"
        },
        "second": {
          "name": "item2"
        },
        "third": {
          "name": "item3"
        }
      };
      $scope.showData = false;

    }
  ]
).directive(
  "expandItem", [
    function() {
      return {
        link: function($scope) {
          $scope.showRdoData = false;

          $scope.subitems = {
            "fir": {
              "names": "subitem1"
            },
            "sec": {
              "names": "subitem2"
            },
            "thd": {
              "names": "subitem3"
            }
          };
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        template: '<tr ng-repeat="row in ::subitems">' +
          '<td style="background-color: red"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-{{showRdoData ? \'minus\' : \'plus\'}}"></i></td>' +
          '<td style="background-color: blueviolet">{{::row.names}}</td></tr>'
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

Can someone help me in getting the data displayed in the table please? The code is present at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gb906akp/). 
Please let me know if the question isn't clear. I will try to rephrase it if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason you were having issues was because the `ngIf` directive does not play well with `ngRepeat` by passing `showData` to the directive via an isolate scope you can move the `ngIf` to the `<td>`'s and achieve the expected behavior. [Here is a link to a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gb906akp/18/)

HTML

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <table ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <thead>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat-start="item in items" ng-click="showData = !showData">
        <td><i class="fa fa-fw fa-{{showData ? 'minus' : 'plus'}}"></i></td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat-end expand-item show-data="showData"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Modified Directive Values

```
replace:true,
template: '<tr ng-repeat="row in ::subitems">' +
            '<td ng-if="showData" style="background-color: red"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-{{showRdoData ? \'minus\' : \'plus\'}}"></i></td>' +
            '<td ng-if="showData" style="background-color: blueviolet">{{::row.names}}</td>' + 
          '</tr>'
```